# In socket i/o, how to send a message from an array of messages to respective room in an array of rooms without any loop?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

socket i/o: I am using nodejs in my php application. I have an array of connected rooms say **rooms={room1,room2,room3}** and an array of respective message say **messages={message1, message2, message3}**.

Till now i am emitting my message as below:

`io.sockets.in('room1').emit('message', 'message1');`

This works fine but i am worried that once number of rooms will increase, looping over all will give performance hit as well as big delays.

Is there any way that i can directly send an array of message to an array of room like following?:

`io.sockets.in(rooms).emit('message', messages);`

which eventually should send message1 to room1... respectively.

thank you.!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a built-in method to do this. However, I also don't think it's necessary for you yet. Here's why I think you should just stick to using a loop for now.

1. How do you think your suggested calls would work? At some point, somebody's code is going to have to create a loop to touch every room and every message. A 3rd party library might have optimized their loop (or it might be really buggy and slow, just depends), but it's still going to have to loop.
2. In a lot of cases it is better to get your features working first and then go back to evaluate and fix slow points in your code. [Read here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) for a lot more guidance on this topic. Note that I'm not advising you to blindly code without thinking ahead, just to not sweat the small stuff. I especially appreciate the way the second answer in the link suggests appropriate considerations for each stage of development.

Comment: you make so much of sense @ashbygeek. I was wondering if there is anything like this. But better i go ahead with current implementation and become greedy only when required :) i will wait for a while if something strikes up to this solution.